# String to byte array in android and IOS

Tags: android, ios

Hi in the below code I am trying to convert string to byte array but expected output is different from IOS.

Android:

```
String jsonString = "{\"i\":1,\"v\":1,\"t\":8,\"s\":\"dbri\",\"n\":50}";
    
byte[] payload = jsonString.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);
```

IOS:

```
let jsonObject = ["i": 1, "v": 1, "t": 8, "s": "dbri", "n": 50] as [String : Any]

        let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: [])

        let data =  Data(jsonData.bytes)
```

Expected output in IOS:

> byte array = [123, 34, 118, 34, 58, 49, 44, 34, 110, 34, 58, 53, 48,
> 44, 34, 116, 34, 58, 56, 44, 34, 115, 34, 58, 34, 100, 98, 114, 105,
> 34, 44, 34, 105, 34, 58, 49, 125]
>
> Android: [123, 34, 105, 34, 58, 49, 44, 34, 118, 34, 58, 49, 44, 34, 116, 34, 58, 56, 44, 34, 115, 34, 58, 34, 100, 98, 114, 105, 34, 44, 34, 110, 34, 58, 53, 48, 125]

Comment: Which programming language are you using? What kind of platform?

Comment: There is need for some informations: What's the languages you posted? What's the iOS code? What's the Android code? A nice tip would be to "reverse the output" and see what's the String equivalent for it. Because as we can see, it's ALMOST the same. The difference being single quotes vs double quotes & the "order" which is different, but shouldn't matter as it's a Dictionary.

Comment: From the output your gave: For iOS: `{\"v\":1,\"n\":50,\"t\":8,\"s\":\"dbri\",\"i\":1}`, and for the other one: `{\'i\': 1, \'v\': 1, \'t\': 8, \'s\': \'dbri\', \'n\': 50}`

Comment: If it is truly JSON, you should be using double quotes `"`. This and Larme's comment suggest that you stringified an actual object to get the string, and you must take in account that key ordering in an object can be inconsistent across platforms (the same data but in different key order). There are also JSON "prettyfy" options that can add spaces new lines etc

Comment: it's in swift ...

Answer (score 0):

With the help of iOS code (since I'm an iOS developer), let's debug...

#### Debugging:

Let's start with converting the output into String back:

```
let iosBytes: [UInt8] = [123, 34, 118, 34, 58, 49, 44, 34, 110, 34, 58, 53, 48, 44, 34, 116, 34, 58, 56, 44, 34, 115, 34, 58, 34, 100, 98, 114, 105, 34, 44, 34, 105, 34, 58, 49, 125]

let androidBytes: [UInt8] = [123, 39, 105, 39, 58, 32, 49, 44, 32, 39, 118, 39, 58, 32, 49, 44, 32, 39, 116, 39, 58, 32, 56, 44, 32, 39, 115, 39, 58, 32, 39, 100, 98, 114, 105, 39, 44, 32, 39, 110, 39, 58, 32, 53, 48, 125]
    
let iOSString = String(data: Data(iosBytes), encoding: .utf8)
print(iOSString)
let androidString = String(data: Data(androidBytes), encoding: .utf8)
print(androidString)
```

Output:

```
$>Optional("{\"v\":1,\"n\":50,\"t\":8,\"s\":\"dbri\",\"i\":1}")
$>Optional("{\'i\': 1, \'v\': 1, \'t\': 8, \'s\': \'dbri\', \'n\': 50}")
```

#### Interpreting:

So, we have ALMOST the same values, with 2 differences:

##### Double quotes vs single quotes:

It seems that SINGLE quote is producing valid JSON in JSON5, but not in "more common JSON".
For instance, in Apple' SDK, it's [`JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions. json5Allowed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/readingoptions) and it's allowed only in macOS12+, iOS15+. for `JSONSerialization` (and I guess `JSONDecoder/JSONEncoder too)`.

So are you sure you're constructing correctly the "String" with
`String jsonString = "{'i': 1, 'v': 1, 't': 8, 's': 'dbri', 'n': 50}";`?

##### Order is different

They are both dictionary, and the order stringified is different. We don't know how you produced the iOS output, but since it's a `Dictionary`, order shouldn't matter. It can matter if you need to encrypt it sometimes, but that's another issue.

Comment: based on your comments updated code

Comment: Please help me on the issue

Comment: any inputs.....

Comment: ` let data =  Data(jsonData.bytes)` -> `let data = jsonData`? Why the extra init? What's your new issue exactly?

Comment: The value inside the JSON object is the same, the order is different: question why does it matter to you? That explanation is missing as for 99% it does NOT matter.